# How to delete the content of a file in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a way to overwrite all of the text content of a file. I am using Unity C#. I am trying to make an A.I. for Unity and I need to overwrite it's original brain with it's improved brain and there cannot be two brains in this text file which is why I need a way to delete all the content of a file through code. Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: Open the file with FileMode.Truncate?

Comment: `System.IO.File.WriteAllText()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the entire content of the file:

```cpp
using (var FileWriter = new StreamWriter("YOUR_FILE_NAME.txt", false))
{
    FileWriter.WriteLine("WRITE SOMETHING HERE");
}
```